# How to portable read a text file line by line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, macos

For processing a text file in bash line by line, I usually implement a while loop like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    local inputFile="$1"
    local fd=""
    local line=""
    exec {fd}<"$inputFile" # open file
    echo "Opened ${inputFile} for read using descriptor ${fd}"
    while IFS='' read -r -u $fd line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "read = \"$line\""
    done
    exec {fd}<&- # close file
    return 0
}
```

This works on my Linux but unfortunately not in OSX. For OSX I currently have to change the code to something like this:

```
exec 3<"$inputFile" # open file
while IFS='' read -r -u 3 line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "read = \"$line\""
done
exec 3<&- # close file
```

But this has the disadvantage, that I have to manage the file descriptor numbers by myself (in the first script, I let bash choose an available file descriptor number).

Did someone have a solution for this which works for both Linux and OSX?

Note that for some reason, I don't want to use piping or I/O redirection to the complete loop like this (because I don't want to execute the loop in a different process):

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "read = \"$line\""
done < "$inputFile"
```

Comment: The last loop will not fork a new process.

Comment: Automatically generated file descriptors appeared in Bash 4.1. OS X uses an antique version of Bash (3.something). So the issue is about portability across versions, not across systems.

Comment: But bash is not Posix shell. You will have portability problems across bash versions and across other implementations of Posix shell (like BSD one). Stick to standard redirection, it is portable and does not fork a subprocess.

Answer (score 3):

The last loop will not fork a new process. You can verify that by printing `"$BASHPID"` in and outside of the loop.

New processes are only created for pipelines. Simple redirections are handled by temporary `dup`s within the bash process.

Feel free to use standard stdin/stdout redirection. It's no more expensive than redirection done with the `exec` builtin.